# Существует ли слово "избрачно"?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, значение-слов, словообразование, семантика

Всю жизнь жила с мыслью, что такое слово существует. Видела уже одно обсуждение на эту тему, но не тут, и к единому мнению люди не пришли, хотя большая часть утверждает, что это всего лишь опечатка. Но, как по мне, это слово – синоним слова "выборочно".
Пример использования: "Его ответы были избрачны".

Answer (score 2):

Официально слова "избрачно" нет — ни в одном словаре, даже в словаре русских народных говоров ([стр. 95](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/12.pdf)). А неофициально — гуляет по разным сайтам (["избрачно"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&ei=IkAvY42hEen6qwHIo7GIDA&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiNuuzi-636AhVp_SoKHchRDME4FBDw0wN6BAgBEEo&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1)).

Никакой дискуссии я не нашла (только неправильное использование этого слова в ["Большом вопросе"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3505465-budet-li-vveden-karantin-v-saratove-s-13-marta-2020-goda.html)), а обнаружила лишь опечатки и явную малограмотность.
Например (как есть):
*Стразы приклеины не по всему рисунку,а избрачно, поэтому смотрится...

Та вообще никого не любит кроме себя любимой это из собак, а людей любит очень избрачно...

Очень избрачно нравиться. Всё таки прикольно бывает...

Избрачно верить в бессмертные силы..

Избрачно-семейных отношений...*

Думаю, что это или описка, или попытка скомбинировать несколько слов: *выборочно* (от выбирать), *избирательно* и *избранный* (от избрать).

Answer (score 2):

1. Слов "***избрачный***" (сочетание РА) и ***изборочный*** (сочетание ОРО) нет в современных словарях, хотя в **ненормированных** текстах они встречаются **довольно часто**.

**Потребность** в этих словах есть, так как слово "выборочный" их не заменяет. ***Избрать*** — это не ***выбрать***, значение приставок разное. Приставка ИЗ относится к выбору из **заданной темы**, которая в данный момент рассматривается, а приставка ВЫ имеет более общее значение.

2. Поэтому я бы не стала называть использование этих слов  **малограмотным**, это просто ненормированная речь — ведь нужное **значение** пользователи определяют верно.
   Но фонетика слов изборочный/избрачный не слишком удачная, да и словообразование выглядит некорректно.

**ВЫБОРОЧНЫЙ**.  Не сплошной, частичный. В-ая проверка. В-ая пахота. В-ая рубка леса.

3. Самое близкое по значению **нормированное** слово — это "***избирательный***", например: избирательный (изборочный) подход.

**ИЗБИРАТЕЛЬНЫЙ**, 1. Относящийся к выборам представителей и должностных лиц путём голосования. И-ое право. И-ая кампания. И. участок. И. бюллетень. 2. **Основанный на свойстве производить отбор**. И-ая память. И-ое действие ядов и лекарственных веществ.

4. Попробуем сравнить варианты «избрачный» и «изборочный». Слово «избрачный», вероятно, соотнесено с глаголом **«избрать»**, но такое словообразование **нехарактерно** для языка, поэтому оно выглядит совсем просторечным. В то же время  «изборочный» встречается в текстах книжного, а не только разговорного  стиля (оно, скорее всего,  просто копирует слово «выборочный»).

Видимо, поэтому  эти слова **не нормируются** словарями. Соответственно,  лучше их  **не использовать**, а заменить словом «избирательный».

Нормированными являются следующие варианты **с корректным словообразованием**, которые к тому же хорошо воспринимаются на слух: *выбрать – выбор – **выбор/очн/ый**, избрать – избирать – **избир/ательн/ый.***